# Using column two radio buttons in DataGrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created two template column in DataGrid.I assigned radio buttons to those columns.I created single selection by calling a javascript function for the first radio button.
 But,I cant't do single selection by calling a javascript function for the second radio button.Also,I can't run independently of each other.

```
      <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <input type="radio" runat="server" id="rd1" onclick="SelectOne(this,'DataGrid')" VALUE="rd1"
       NAME="RadioGroup1" />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">

     <ItemTemplate>
      <input type="radio" runat="server" id="rd2" onclick="test(this,'DataGrid')" VALUE="rd2" 
      NAME="RadioGroup2" />      
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Javascript Code:

```
  <script  language="javascript">
  function SelectOne(rd1,DataGrid)
  {
  all=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(i=0;i<all.length;i++)
  {
  if(all.type=="radio")
   {
   var count=all.id.indexOf(DataGrid+'__ctl');
  if(count!=-1)
   {
    all.checked=false;
   }
   }
  }
   rd1.checked=true;
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to run the radio buttons as server side controls?  It may be easier to manage if you remove the runat=server and just emit a unique group name instead for each radio button that is part of the same group since that will prevent asp.net from changing the ID's.  You can then check the selected values using Request["RadioGroupName"] instead of with the server control value property.

This will keep the groups working correctly, and it will make your javascript to select the radio buttons simpler.

Comment: First of all,thanks for your interesting.As you mentioned,How can I do a modification within my javascript code?

Comment: It was not clear to me what you were intending to do with your javascript.  If your goal is simply to have them act as a single group the javascript should be unnecessary if the name value of all of the radio buttons can be made the same, which you would be able to accomplish by removing the runat="server" attribute, and naming them the same.